# Adding one to numbers bigger than ten

Tags: reference-request, students-mistakes, arithmetic

If someone asks you

> Tell me the next number (add one) after the number 
>  
>   one million two hundred thirty-one thousand ninety-nine,

do you known if it is a common error that the first number that comes to mind, their answer, is "one million two hundred thirty-two thousand"?

In general, do you know any document or reference for usual errors when counting numbers? All references I've found are not applicable to numbers greater than ten.

Comment: When I was young, a common trick was to ask "What is 1000, plus 1000, plus 20, plus 20, plus 20, plus 20, plus 10, plus 10?" with some answering "3000."

Comment: Is that called “miscarrying a 1?”

Comment: I saw a version of that trick with a prepared prop: the numbers were printed on a card, and were uncovered one at a time by the person trying to trick you. You were asked to keep a running total. It went 10, 1000, 20, 1000, 30, 1000, 40, and almost everybody says 4000 at the end

Comment: 231,100
one million two hundred thirty-one thousand one hundred